# rewriting an AJAX call in Angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular

I m trying to rewrite an Ajax call in Angular. But getting always 401 Unauthorized. When i run the Ajax call, it works perfectly.
Any idea how can i transfrom it to a Angular http request ? 
Thanks...

```
send(project) {
        let self = this;
        self.tasksURI = 'http://xxxx:xxxx/xx/xx/' + project + '/_apis/build/builds'
        self.PAT = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        self.ajax = function (uri, method, data) {
            var request = {
                url: uri,
                type: method,
                contentType: "application/json",
                accepts: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "xxxxxxxxxx"));
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR);
                }
            };
            return $.ajax(request);
        }

        self.ajax(self.tasksURI, 'GET').done((data) => {
            console.log(data)

        });
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

In angular you try this:

**In Angular**

```
post(
    this.serverUrl, dataObjToPost,
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
           'Content-Type':  'application/json',
         })
    }
)
```

**back-end (I use php)**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
print_r($request);
```

See [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/58106956#58106956)

Comment: xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "xxxxxxxxxx")); exactly this part causing me problem. i dint know how to handle this part int the request

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned you're getting "Unauthorised" judging from your situation this could mean 2 of things:

1. You are not providing any `Authorization` header
2. Your `Authorization` header is invalid

Since you're rewriting this I think it's most likely that you forgot to apply the `Authorization` header to your `httpOptions`

From the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#http-headers):

```
httpOptions.headers =
  httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'my-new-auth-token');
```

Comment: xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "xxxxxxxxxx")); 
exactly this part causing me problem. i dint know how to handle this part int the request